# Import fixed width data in R

Tags: r, fixed-width

I have a problem importing a file in R. The file correctly organized must contain 5 million records and 22 columns. I cannot separate the data base properly. I tried it with this code:

```
content <- scan("filepath",'character',sep='~') # Read the file as a single line
# To split content in lines:
lines <- regmatches(content,gregexpr(".{211}",content)) #Each line must have 211 characters with 5 million rows in total
x <- tempfile()
library(erer)
write.list(lines,x)
data <- read.fw(x, widths = c(12,9,9,3,4,8,1,1,3,3,3,1,12,14,13,30,8,9,12,6,6,27))
unlink(x)
```

Each record has numbers and letters. I don't know what I can correct to separate in columns properly.

All rows looks like this:
1000100060040000000000808040512000000188801072010010010000000000000 CABANILLAS       GONZALES      MARIA                         MANUEL CABANILLAS            MARIA GONZALES               00000000000000000000000

I want to separate it according to the widths specified in the function
It includes some spaces that I cannot include in the final view

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Since the problem has clearly something to do with the structure of your data, could you post a sample of it? We probably have to reproduce the situation on our own systems to understand the problem.

Comment: I notice that the column widths that you give above only sum to 194, not 211.

Comment: "I cannot separate the data base properly." is not very descriptive on where the problem is.  Have you tried reading the file directly with the `read.fwf()` function or look at the "readr" package?

Comment: To use read.fwf with the original file?

Comment: Yes, use read.fwf() with the original file.  You need to make sure that the widths are correct, and based on the sample provide, it doesn't they don't appear correct.

Comment: The problem I have is that the original file hast type file extension and I am not sure how to read it in R properly. Can you help with that?